# Left Join errors out: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

***Edit

```
df_joint = df_raw.join(df_items,on='x',how='left')
```

The titled exception occurred in Apache Spark 2.4.5

df_raw has data of 2 columns "x", "y" and df_items is an empty data frame of schema with some other columns

left join is happening on a value to null, which should get the whole data from 1st dataframe with null columns from the 2nd dataframe.

It is completely working fine when "X" is float, how ever when I casted "X" to string its throwing error of implicit  cartesian product

i received this error with spark 2.4.5.

Why it is happening and how to resolve this with out enabling the spark cross join
`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")`

Comment: Why not use explicit `df_raw.crossJoin(df_items)` ?

Comment: @mazaneicha cross join will result in a duplicated column `x`

Comment: Column can be dropped before join, especially since I suspect its there only to have something to do a left join on.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug in Spark, but if you just want to add columns, you can do the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_joint = df_raw.select(
    '*',
    *[F.lit(None).alias(c) for c in df_items.columns if c not in df_raw.columns]
)
```